Can you assess Moderation with ANCOVA?
I am using SPSS for analysis with 1 group IV (4 levels), one DV measured at time 1 and time 2 for each participant in each group, and one covariate measured once at time 2 or for each participant in each group. Each group receives a different type of intervention during the time between time 1 and time 2.
I plan to do a 2 x 4 Mixed ANCOVA with the within-group variable as time. Can I use this same model to assess the moderation effect of the CV? I want to see, depending on the level of CV, which group/(intervention type) had greater increases in DV.
I was thinking of just doing a follow-up moderation; however, I am unsure if I can do so while accounting for time 1 DV scores in the model by having it as a within-subjects factor.
There are established relationships between the CV and DV, IV and CV; however, less is known about the extent of the relationship between each level of the IV (group) and the DV.
I would like to find out:

I want to see if the effect of the IV on the DV is significant when I adjust for the CV (do the groups differ in their ability to increase the DV from time 1 to time 2)
I want to see the order of the groups ability to increase the DV from time 1 to time 2 (which group is best, second, third, last).
I want to see if the relationship between the IV and IV changes at different CV points. (for different levels of the CV/moderator, which group/(intervention type) had greater increases in DV).

I am not sure if these two investigations are fundamentally opposed to each other (e.g., both can't be significant at the same time due to violations of each other's model assumptions).
Thank you!

Well, I would do a multilevel model, not any kind of ANCOVA. An ANOVA (and similarly an ANCOVA) assumes sphericity, and this is not usually  a reasonable assumption.

Thank you, but I am not sure if that will answer my questions, will it? Why is sphericity not a reasonable assumption my case?

If there are only 2 observations (one at each time point) for each individual, is there some reason why you can’t just use the difference in DV values as the outcome and avoid all the mixed-model issues?

Using change scores as the outcome variable has drawbacks. Collapsing data into change scores can obscure important details about individual time points, reducing valuable information on patterns over time. It also assumes equal variability of change scores across groups, which might not be true, affecting validity. Additionally, if pre-test scores are not well-matched, change scores may introduce bias. In contrast, a repeated measures design with time as a within-subject factor inherently controls for baseline differences, providing a more accurate assessment of treatment effects.

Sphericity, in general, is not reasonable. However, with only two time points, it may not be as unreasonable here as it usually is.

Although change scores have drawbacks as outcome values in many circumstances, in this situation it would just be an extension of paired t-tests (provided that each individual was only in 1 treatment group). Or, if you want to use the time 1 DV value as a predictor, do that with the corresponding time 2 DV value as the outcome, as Noah suggests in this answer. I'd be wary of using a covariate measured at time 2 as a predictor of the DV at time 1, as you seem to propose, unless you know that it doesn't change over time.
